# Ways to round the numbers by removing the decimal part in perl

Tags: perl, decimal, perl-module

I want to round the numeric data by removing the decimal part. I dont want to use "**sprintf**". Is there any other methods to do in perl. Please help me with this.
For instance,
if the value is 4.5 then output should be 5 and for 4.2 its 4 and 4.7 its 5 respectively.
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Yes its duplicate one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `int` keyword.

```
my $value = 4.5;
print int( $value + 0.5 );
```

However, the `int` perl documentation warns against using `int` for rounding:

> Returns the integer portion of EXPR.  If EXPR is omitted, uses $_. 
>   You should not use this function for rounding: one because it
>   truncates towards 0, and two because machine representations of
>   floating-point numbers can sometimes produce
>                  counterintuitive results.  For example, "int(-6.725/0.025)" produces -268 rather than the correct -269; that's
>   because it's really more like -268.99999999999994315658 instead. 
>   Usually, the "sprintf", "printf", or the "POSIX::floor" and
>                  "POSIX::ceil" functions will serve you better than will int().